# How can I resolve Automatically fetching dates in datetimepicker?

Tags: jquery-ui, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using Bootstrap datetimepicker. When I open a datetimepicker calendar, without selecting any date if I click outside its automatically taking current date and time. How can I resolve this issue? After selecting date only the selected date should display on the screen. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bootstrap 3 Datepicker v4 by eonasdan set

```
useCurrent: false
```

http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#usecurrent